# Issues with rounding cells in an Array while still displaying an UNrounded copy of it

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, rounding

This is a program for calculating tips. I need to get hoursArray[] to round each cell normally (using Math.round() is the best way to my knowledge). The problem is that I still need the UNrounded hoursArray[] to be stored into totalHours[].

Example of desired output: Bob works 33.49 hours and Sara works 33.5 hours, the tips for the week are $200.00

So Bob's hours should round down to 33, and Sara's would round up to 34. **You would be able to see the difference in tip earnings with Sara having more than Bob.** But the total hours for the week would still be displayed as 66.99.

***Right now this program does everything else it's supposed to do***, I just can't figure out how to round each cell of hoursArray[] and still keep the totalHours[] intact.

How can I round each cell in hoursArray[] and still keep the UNrounded values stored into totalHours[]? Do I use a clone() of hoursArray? arrayCopy()? I'm stuck...

**The problem-area is marked**, and between *lines 33 and 43*. **Math.floor()** is necessary because I need the program to round the tips downward.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Tips_Calculation2 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    float totalTips = 0;
    float totalHours = 0;

    System.out.print("How many employees worked for the week?: ");
    int numberOfEmps = scan.nextInt();


    System.out.println("\nEnter the names of all " + numberOfEmps + " employees");


    String[] namesArray = new String[numberOfEmps];
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEmps; i++)
    {
        namesArray[i] = scan.next();
    }


    System.out.println("\nEnter the amount of hours each person worked for the week: ");






 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////**THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK**///////////////
    int counter = 0;
    float[] hoursArray = new float[namesArray.length];
    for(int n = 0; n < namesArray.length; n++)
    {
        System.out.print(namesArray[n] + ": ");
        hoursArray[n] = scan.nextFloat();
        totalHours = totalHours + hoursArray[n];
        counter++;
    }
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////






    System.out.println("\nTotal hours: " + totalHours);
    System.out.print("\nEnter the amount of money to be distributed as tips: $");
    totalTips = scan.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("---- OUTPUT ----");
    System.out.println();


    int x = 0;
    for(int a = 0; a < namesArray.length; a++)
    {
        System.out.println(namesArray[a] + ": " + "$" + Math.floor(((hoursArray[x]/totalHours) * totalTips)));
        x++;                                          
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: floor() will always round down to the next largest number smaller than your input. If you want values like 33.5 to be round up to 34, you need to use round(). Your problem is in the calculation. I assume you mean something like that: Math.round(hoursArray[x])/totalHours * totalTips. Your array of totalHours is not affected as long as you do not store the rounded value in the specified array "cell"

Comment: I need to keep the Math.floor() because it has to round tips downward, I edited this in my question for future viewers. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Then you can do as follows: Math.round(hoursArray[x])/totalHours * Math.floor(totalTips). This will round down or up the hours at the specified array-index, will not affect your totalHours which stay on the correct value and will round down your totalTip.

Comment: Thanks! That really gave me a good boost as to where I need this program to be. But the individual tips for each person needs to be rounded down using Math.floor(). Using Math.floor()(totalTips) doesn't do anything as far as rounding down individual tips alone.

Comment: If I understand you the right way now, you mean this: Math.floor(Math.round(hoursArray[x])/totalHours * totalTips);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you've marked looks ok: hoursArray will indeed contain the (not rounded) number of hours each one has worked.

Your problem is later when you do the rounding. From your description I understand that you want to round the number of hours, not the resulting tip. Therefore, your calculation needs to be something like:

```
Math.round(hoursArray[x]) * totalTips / totalHours
```

Also, when you calculate the total number of hours, you want to add the *rounded* number of hours, otherwise your tips will not add up to the desired total:

```
totalHours = totalHours + Math.round(hoursArray[n]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As told in the comments to your question already, you can calculate the tip of each person and round it "down" by using this prompt:

```
Math.floor(Math.round(hoursArray[x])/totalHours * totalTips);
```

`Math.round(hoursArray[x])` will round up or down the hours (33.3 to 33, 33.7 to 34). `Math.floor()` will then round down the calculated individual tip (333.3 to 333, 333.7 to 333).

Comment: this method still leaves .0 at the end of every result. I'm trying to get it to where I don't have any .0's at all at the end of each result. Like 30.918 would become 30, 5.555 would become 5, etc.

Comment: Then you can use type casting: (int)Math.floor((int)(Math.round(hoursArray[x])/totalHours * totalTips));